# How can I make a sprite duck with a ducking png?

Tags: python, pygame

I loaded a ducking png for my sprite, so when I press the down arrow, he ducks and when he ducks the rectangle gets smaller, which is good, but the rectangle seems like the sprite is floating instead of ducking at the place he is. It's like he sits on the air. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Two options -

- You could make the ducking graphic the same size as the regular standing graphic, and just place the sprite in the bottom part of the image (with the rest transparent)
- You could reposition the box manually to move the y-position nearer to the ground when the ducking occurs

Of these, the first is the easiest to implement, but the second would be necessary if you're also using the rectangle for e.g. hit-testing.

Comment: I tried both of those options before I even posted in here, the problem is that I need to use the second option to use rectangle hit-testing and etc, Now the first option I also tried, but it somehow messed up the png and the rectangle can be visible even when I use set_colorkey, but that's not really the problem an since I try the second option, any ideas how to do that? I can send the code if you want to check and tell me where to put the command doing that.

Comment: What you need to do is a little bit of math: new y position = old y position + (full image height - duck image height).

Comment: Now in order to do that, I need to get the coordinates of the sprite, and set it some new coordinates, any ideas how to do it? is there a function doing that? Thanks for your help too.